# Iterate (loop) through a column in a pyspark dataframe and create stacked bargraph for each group of items

Tags: for-loop, pyspark, charts, iteration, databricks

I have referenced the following to do the same in databricks pyspark:

[Iterating through a dataframe and plotting each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044018/iterating-through-a-dataframe-and-plotting-each-column)

[Iterate through columns to generate barplots while using groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088994/iterate-through-columns-to-generate-barplots-while-using-groupby)

[How can we loop through items in a dataframe and create a bar charts for each 'group' of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68977105/how-can-we-loop-through-items-in-a-dataframe-and-create-a-bar-charts-for-each-g)

but I am not able to write something similar that will work in pyspark.

My spark dataframe looks like this:

```
data = [{'id1': '1150', 'org':'south_org', 'id2':300, 'fields':'firstname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1150', 'org':'south_org', 'id2':300, 'fields':'lastname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1150', 'org':'south_org', 'id2':300, 'fields':'streetaddress', 'value':'missing'},
        {'id1': '1150', 'org':'south_org', 'id2':300, 'fields':'state', 'value':'missing'},
        {'id1': '1150', 'org':'south_org', 'id2':300, 'fields':'zip', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '3000', 'org':'north_org', 'id2':310, 'fields':'firstname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '3000', 'org':'north_org', 'id2':310, 'fields':'lastname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '3000', 'org':'north_org', 'id2':310, 'fields':'streetaddress', 'value':'error'},
        {'id1': '3000', 'org':'north_org', 'id2':310, 'fields':'state', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '3000', 'org':'north_org', 'id2':310, 'fields':'zip', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1110', 'org':'west_org', 'id2':315, 'fields':'firstname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1110', 'org':'west_org', 'id2':315, 'fields':'lastname', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1110', 'org':'west_org', 'id2':315, 'fields':'streetaddress', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1110', 'org':'west_org', 'id2':315, 'fields':'state', 'value':'complete'},
        {'id1': '1110', 'org':'west_org', 'id2':315, 'fields':'zip', 'value':'complete'}
       ]
```

I have 130 million rows due to long format

I would like to create a separate bargraph after iterating through each id1 values. My approach is to iterate through that column and create a bargraph.

I tried the following approaches:
when I first tried converting it to pandas df, i got an OOM error.

I also followed along the suggested codes and in some, I got some errors:

```
grouped = data.groupby('id1')

for i, (groupname, group) in enumerate(grouped):
  axes[i].plot(group.id1, group.values, kind='stacked')
  axes[i].set_title(groupname)
```

This next one also did not work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

for id1, data in wide_df:
  plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
  sns.barplot(data=data, x='fields',y='status')
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
```

What I am trying to achieve is this, for each id1 (I have 1200 unique id1s), is to create individual graph like below, where the categories in the y-axis is the 'fields' column from the spark dataframe

[image: expected output]

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer, I hope:

I think I am on for something on this one. I was able to create individual dataframe per id1, but still working on how to create a bargraph from each dataframe. HOpefully someone can guide me on how to add them.

```
for i in data.select('id1').distinct().collect():
  print(i)
  identifation1 = i.id1
  per_id = data.filter(data.id1== identification1)
  per_df = per_id.groupBy('fields','value').count().sort('fields')
```

resulting to something like:

```
Row(id1 = 1150)
+-----------+---------+--------+
|     fields|    value|   count|
+-----------+---------+--------+
|  firstname| complete|      10|
|  firstname|    error|       8|
|   lastname|  missing|      25|
|   lastname|    error|       2|
|        zip| complete|      35|
...
|otherfields| complete|      50|
+-----------+---------+--------+
```

I need to move on and create bar graph